# ServerVariables and POST Data

Tags: .net, asp.net, post, request.servervariables

I've got a piece of tracking code which is capturing `REMOTE_HOST`, `SERVER`, `REQUEST_METHOD`, `SCRIPT_NAME` and `QUERY_STRING`. It grabs these from `ServerVariables` and sticks them in a database by user and IP.

What is the best way to pick up the exact contents of what was posted back to a URL in ASP.NET? Is there an `HTTP_POST`? I'd rather not grab something and then have to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about something like the Request.Form collection.

It's a NameValueCollection object with all the POST-ed data.

Edit:

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx

Comment: Can you get to this from the Global.asax's _BeginRequest? Has Request.Form been instantiated yet? Had an issue yesterday going for Session["user"] because Session isn't available yet in the request cycle.

Comment: I'm not sure about that one ... sorry.  Just try it, see what happens :-)